# How to use WhatsApi4J to work with whatsapp

Tags: whatsapp

We are trying to connect to whatsapp using the  WhatsApi4J.jar . I had downloaded the  WhatsApi4J.jar file from github , but there is no example on how to use the API. Can anyone tell me the process ?? i want to

1) register the phone 
2) send messages using that phone .